# Load Selected item of combobox from roaming settings

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8, microsoft-metro

I have a combobox

```
<ComboBox x:Name="cityPicker">
    <ComboBoxItem IsSelected="True">
        <x:String>
            city1
        </x:String>
    </ComboBoxItem>
    <ComboBoxItem>
        <x:String>
            city2
        </x:String>
    </ComboBoxItem>
```

When user select 'city2' then I save it to roaming settings in `selectedCity` key.

I need to load this value from roaming settings when user start application after exit and after back to this page from another one.

With this code value saved to RoamingSetting, and when i start application after change city, roamingsettings have its value. But Combobox doesn't retrieve it. Combobox selected item stay empty.

How to change selected item in combobox programmatically?

```
 protected override void LoadState(Object navigationParameter, Dictionary<String, Object> pageState)
 {
     var roamingSettings = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.RoamingSettings;
     if (roamingSettings.Values.ContainsKey("selectedCity"))
     {
         cityPicker.SelectedValue = roamingSettings.Values["selectedCity"].ToString();
     }
 }

public StartPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            cityPicker.SelectionChanged += cityPicker_SelectionChanged;
        }

        void cityPicker_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            var roamingSettings =
               Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.RoamingSettings;
            var cityPick = cityPicker.SelectedItem as ComboBoxItem;
            if (cityPick != null) roamingSettings.Values["selectedCity"] = cityPick.Content;
        }
```

I can do it only by change `SelectedIndex`. But this is not what I want.

Comment: where is the code which persists the data?

Comment: I update question. In debug mode value saved successfully and roamingSettings.Values["selectedCity"] contain needed value.

Comment: so, what's the problem? Your post does not explain in particularly well.

Comment: I start application. Then i change city in combobox. Then i Close application. Then I start application. But when application opened city not changed (its stay default). I need that choosed city was saved. But now, when i start application, i have combobox with no  selected city.

Comment: How to change selected item in combobox programmatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I think I know what's happening here. You have populated your `ComboBox` with `ComboBoxItems` and are later trying to set its `SelectedValue` to a `string`. When you do that, the `ComboBox` checks to see if it contains that new value. It uses `ComboBoxItem.Equals()` to perform this check, which checks for reference equality. Obviously, this check will always return `false` since the types for the two objects being compared are different, which is why the `ComboBox` is not able to find it and hence display it. The correct thing to do here would be to set your `ComboBox`'s `ItemsSource` to a strongly typed collection of strings. If you do that, the `ComboBox` will use `String.Equals()` for the equality check which performs the equality using value type equality semantics.

Assume you have a `ComboBox` with its `name` set to "comboBox." In your codebehind event handler handler:

```
IEnumerable<string> foo = new[] { "A", "B", "C" };
comboBox.ItemsSource = foo;
comboBox.SelectedValue = "B"; // This should work
```

Here's an example which is directly related to your code

XAML:

```
<ComboBox x:Name="cityPicker" />
```

C#:

```
public StartPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    cityPicker.ItemsSource = new[] { "city1", "city2" };
    cityPicker.SelectionChanged += OnCityPickerSelectionChanged;
}

void OnCityPickerSelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    // get your roaming settings
    var selectedItem = cityPicker.SelectedItem;
    roamingSettings.Values["SelectedCity"] = (string) selectedItem;
}

protected override void LoadState(...)
{
    // get roaming settings, perform key check
    cityPicker.SelectedValue = (string) (roamingSettings.Values["SelectedCity"]);
}
```

Obviously, the "correct" way to do this is to have a view-model which exposes an `ObservableCollection<string>`. You would set this view model as the data context and then set up a binding between your `ItemsSource` and the view-models `ObservableCollection<string>`. This is probably an exercise for a different day though!

Comment: Thank for help. Your code work well if i put it after InitializeComponent(); but it doesn't work if i put comboBox.SelectedValue = "B" in LoadState method. So... I'm confused.

Comment: make sure you aren't storing it as a `ComboBoxItem` but rather, as a string. Remember, you want value type equality semantics here! Make sure this line `var cityPick = cityPicker.SelectedItem as ComboBoxItem;` is `var cityPick = cityPicker.SelectedItem as string;`

Comment: yes, i'm sure... I try combobox.SelectedIndex and its work well in LoadState method. i don't understand what wrong.

Comment: see my latest example, I find it hard to believe that it doesn't work.

Comment: I'm not familiar with windows 8 programming so I don't know WHEN `LoadState` gets called, could it be your `ComboBox` isn't initialized at that time? Try to step through your code and see that you are getting the correct value out of your `roamingSettings` and that the `ComboBox` is properly initialized and loaded.